# How to get the following two list?

Tags: list, python-3.x

Hello I am working with some lists I have the following list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would like to get the these two lists from a:

```
b = [2,3,4,5,6]
c = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I would like to get the firt one removing the first element of a and the second one removing the last element of a, I tried:

```
b = a
c = a

b.pop(0)
c.pop(len(a)-1)

print(b)
print(c)
print(a)
```

However the output is:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

that is affecting my fist list, I am not sure about what I am doing, I would like to appreciate support with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not modify the original list - it's simpler than you think, just [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) the input list passing the right indexes. Try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = a[1:]
c = a[:-1]


a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]   
b
=> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the support I was thinking in a more complicated way but this is very simple and I got the desired output thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

I think slicing would be ok:
`b =a[1:];`
`c =a[:-1]`